# How to calculate Zscore in R

Tags: r

I have log2ratio values of each chromosome position (137221 coordinates) for different samples (15 samples). I want to calculate the Zscore of log2ratio for each chromosome position (row). Also i want to exclude first three columns because it contains ID. There are also some NAs in between the variables..

Thanking you in advance

Comment: see `scale` for Z-score.

Comment: @Ben i tried scale..but erroe

Comment: @Kryo, maybe you could post some sample data and the code you've tried.  That'd help...

Comment: ProbeID Chromosome Chr_Position sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 StdDeviation rowMean
1 CHR10FS003000293 10 3000293 0.132 1.098 -0.044 0.46344411 0.7275833333
2 CHR10FS003018825 10 3018825 0.524 0.170 0.424 0.20971169 0.3574166667                       This is my data source. each row corresponds to chromosome coordinates and row from 4 to n corresponds to samples.the variables are log2ratio. i have calculated the rowMeans and standard deviation of log2ratio for each row. Now i want to compute Zscore for each row. `there are also some NA in the variables   .

Comment: @Ben sorry for not being clear..

Comment: @Ben sorry for not being clear..I want to calculate zscore for each row. i tried using:                                               for (idx in 1:nrow(df)) {
  this_row <- unlist(df[idx, 4:15, drop = T])
  znorm_row <- (this_row - Finaltable[idx ,16)/Finaltable[idx, 17]
} , but since there are NA it showing error..

Answer (score 1):

It's not *completely* clear what you want. If you want a Z-score for the entire row (i.e., its mean divided by standard error) for all but the first three rows then

```
f <- function(x) {
     mean(x,na.rm=TRUE)/(sd(x,na.rm=TRUE)*sqrt(length(na.omit(x)))) 
}
apply(as.matrix(df[-(1:3),]),1,f)
```

will do it.  That gives you a vector equal to the number of columns (minus 3).

If you want entire columns of normalized data (Z-scores) then I think

```
t(scale(t(as.matrix(df[-(1:3),]))))
```

should work.  If neither of those work, you need to post a reproducible example -- or at least tell us precisely what the error messages are.

Comment: sorry for not being clear..I want to calculate zscore for each row. i tried using:                                               for (idx in 1:nrow(df)) {
  this_row <- unlist(df[idx, 4:15, drop = T])
  znorm_row <- (this_row - Finaltable[idx ,16)/Finaltable[idx, 17]
} , but since there are NA it showing error..

Comment: using t(scale(t(as.matrix(df[-(1:3),]))))...................Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric

Comment: using  your first suggestion.   Error:                      1. In mean.default(x, na.rm = TRUE) :                     
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In var(if (is.vector(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm) :
  NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: data.frame': 137221 obs. of  17 variables:
 $ ProbeID                     : chr  "CHR10FS003000293" "CHR10FS003018825" "CHR10FS003037417" "CHR10FS003056065" ...
 $ Chromosome                  : chr  "10" "10" "10" "10" ...
 $ Chr_Position                : chr  "3000293" "3018825" "3037417" "3056065" ...
 $ X536827A01_CMFS01_segMNT.txt: num  0.132 0.524 0.094 -0.053 0.133 -0.398 -0.051 -0.049 -0.035 0.407 ...
 $ SD                          : num  0.463 0.21 0.408 0.19 0.222 ...
 $ rowMean1[, 4]               : num  0.7276 0.3574 0.4717 -0.0149 0.1499 ...